# Cannot read property 'URL' of null on Form submit with Formik

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, formik

I am trying to test my login form component in ReactJS using Jest and Enzyme. I am using Formik to handle the form. I want to test if error component appear with `Input` component if `input` field value is empty and `Login` button is pressed. Following is my code so far I have done in test:

```
it("Should give error on email and password when login clicked", async () => {
  const store = getOrCreateStore();
  const wrap = mount(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LoginPage />
    </Provider>
  );

  const form = wrap.find(".auth-board").find("form");
  const formBody = form.find(".form-body");

  const emailField = formBody.find(".form-group").at(0);
  const emailError = emailField.find(".error-validate");
  const passwordField = formBody.find(".form-group").at(1);
  const passwordError = passwordField.find("div").find(".error-validate");

  expect(emailError.length).toBe(0);
  expect(passwordError.length).toBe(0);

  form.simulate("submit");

  await setTimeout(async () => {
    wrap.update();
    await wrap.instance().forceUpdate();
    const wrapAfter = wrap.update();

    const formAfter = wrapAfter.find(".auth-board").find("form");
    const formBodyAfter = formAfter.find(".form-body");

    const emailFieldAfter = formBodyAfter.find(".form-group").at(0);
    const emailErrorAfter = emailFieldAfter.find(".error-validate");
    const passwordFieldAfter = formBodyAfter.find(".form-group").at(1);
    const passwordErrorAfter = passwordFieldAfter.find("div").find(".error-validate");

    expect(emailErrorAfter.length).toBe(1);
    expect(passwordErrorAfter.length).toBe(1);

    wrap.unmount();
    wrapAfter.unmount();
  }, 0);
});
```

I get an exception when I run the test, saying:

```
(node:19268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'URL' of null
at new XMLHttpRequest (/home/fawad-khalil/Documents/project/lunchon-web/node_modules/jsdom/lib/jsdom/living/xmlhttprequest.js:112:42)
at dispatchXhrRequest (/home/fawad-khalil/Documents/project/lunchon-web/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:19:19)
at new Promise (<anonymous>)
at xhrAdapter (/home/fawad-khalil/Documents/project/lunchon-web/node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:11:10)
at dispatchRequest (/home/fawad-khalil/Documents/project/lunchon-web/node_modules/axios/lib/core/dispatchRequest.js:59:10)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:19268) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 4)
(node:19268) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

After playing around a bit with the test code, I have come to find that the exception occurs due to the statement `form.simulate("submit");` and it does not occur if the statement is not there. Now if the submit event is simulated then exception occurs and the last 2 `expect` statements do not get executed and the test is reported to be passed in the console. Does somebody know how to tackle this behaviour?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. My stack trace also shows a combination of `jsdom` and `axios`. Did you found a solution?

Comment: @FranCano the solution was to not to test the functionality and hence submit of Formik because unit testing the 3rd party libraries is not a recommended practice.

Comment: I actually managed to fix the test by adding more assertions. What was happening was that the test was finishing before all the AJAX requests where finished. `jsdom` will destroy the mock `window` object immediately after the test finishes, but the pending AJAX requests done by axios where executing code that was trying to access `window.URL`. Hence the warning. Adding async assertions that forced the test to wait until after all requests where finished fixed the issue